# Place to upload tar file for users of my app to download

Tags: android, file-upload

Intention of the app: One time download data(tar file, 10Mb) from the server which my app uses.

Problem: I don't own a domain or a server space or have any idea where to upload the data securely which my app can download. Requirement is to download data securely and have analytics for it.

Do I have to own a server space and write php(or server) code to authenticate user and do all the stuff for downloading 10Mb of data?

I think there will be companies providing facilities like this but I am not sure, since I have not done much of server side coding.

Thoughts: I have uploaded files in rapidshare as a free user, which allows downloads for limited number of people, Is it a right way to go about it? i.e get premium account and use the url generated for download in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a web host. They're not that expensive and you get good control over what's going on. You don't need to script anything if you don't want to since most hosts have statistics you can watch, but if you want to have your own stats a simple PHP script should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 may be an option. You can upload via their web based console, which gives you the URL of your uploaded object. You pay tiny amounts for storage and per PUT and GET, after the free tier.